# Sculpt Mode – Turn off zoom on Option/Alt pen click?

Tags: sculpt

I'm using a tablet, when I option (alt) click with the pen tip to rotate. It zooms way into my model. Is there a setting for this? 
Thanks for any help. Cheers!

Comment: Please write a proper answer to your own question in the answer section, not a comment. You can then mark it as accepted as well. Read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Blender > User Preferences > Auto Perspective (uncheck). Cheers